# how to convert frontpage.php to dynamic page?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, frontpage

front page on WordPress theme is static and I can only edit it from the panel in PHP 
I need to convert it to a dynamic page and edit it with builder or editor on the dashboard

Comment: Have you tried going to Settings > Reading and setting "your homepage displays" to "a static page"?

Comment: yes but it always the static page is the front page I think frontpage.php is overrides any settings and always its the main page

Comment: [`front-page.php`, if it exists, will be used for your "static" home page content.](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#front-page-display) (Note: not `frontpage.php`.) But the "static" front page merely means it's displaying a page's content, not the posts; it doesn't (or shouldn't) mean that you can't edit the page in the editor. Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/368121/edit) to show us the content of `front[-]page.php`.

Comment: I only mean that the main(home) page on my website came from front-page.php(from child theme )
I need to make another main page creates by a builder not from front-page.php
it refuses